# Trying to import products from csv with allimport woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, csv, woocommerce, wpallimport

I have a csv generated by an API  with products.
Each product is a variable product. I'm trying to import them using allimport.
The problem is that the generated file is different from the example that allimport recommends.
[allimport-example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6LnT.png)

[csv example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKLjp.png)

Basically, the CSV that i'm getting is structed that first row contains most of the data from a product , price, category, pictures, and the next rows contain the variation  ( size ) and model barcode.

I've used the option "All products with variations are rouped with a unique value that is the same for each variation and unique for each product", but the output is this : [allimport csv output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yU9S.png)

Is there any way to make it work, or is the csv structure just bad?